# Highlighting a listView item when app starts

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, selecteditem, listselectionlistener

I want to have the first item on my listView selected when the app runs and the menu is opened for the first time (without the need of clicking). Can anyone help me?
I would also like to be able to draw a small vertical line on the right border of the selected item to highlight it, but I couldn't find another way to highlight an item other than changing the background...

[image]

The xml regarding the listView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/slider_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="186dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#368ee0"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#44444444"
    android:divider="#b0e0e6"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Edit 1:

In my MainActivity I am trying to follow one of the suggestions and set the background color of the item before displaying the contents. The relevant lines are:

```
private ListView mDrawerList;
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();//which for instance i use as String url = rowItems.get(position).getPageUrl();

mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideitemListener());
```

And after I am trying something like this:

```
((RowItem)mDrawerList.getItemAtPosition(0)).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(68, 68, 68));
```

But rowItems do not have a setBackgroundColor method. I should get the item from the listView (mDrawerList), but is filled with RowItems.

Comment: Change background of first item to selection color if you have a custom item.

Comment: the items are created dinamically in the adapter, I actually dont know how to do this...

Comment: post your codes what you have tried till yet

Comment: @kalidossrajendran hi, thanks for trying to help me. I just uploaded what I think could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (position == selectedListItem)
  {
    //TODO: set the proper selection color here:
    renderer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
  } 


     try this you can just update zeroth position element to always set a different color
```

Comment: hi, thanks for trying to help me. What actually is the renderer?

Comment: that can be your item or say view object just set the background of same that's it

Comment: Ok, it works, but I am not getting the right color (#44444444 in rgb?? should be a blue but is brown :S) Now I need to change the color of this item after I press another item...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            if (position == 0){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(68, 68, 68));
            }

Comment: yes, i was wondering why it was wrong using a HEX-RGB converter...
It's almost done, I am gona give you points. Thanks a lot.
If you have 2 more minutes, could you tell me please where can I change its color back after I clicked another item? (is not automatic with listSelector, since I directly changed the background without any click)

Comment: use some flag to detect if view is loaded for the first time and set condtion for first item like  if(!isSetOnce){ if (position == selectedListItem)
  {
    //TODO: set the proper selection color here:
    renderer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
  }  isSetonce=true; }

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is

```
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        ...
    }
}
```

After using this mode you can specify different backgrounds using selectors.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I am already changing the backgrounds when I click the items, what I need is to set the "home" item to be already colored when the app starts, before clicking it.